How to make outhouses less icky?
I plan to build an outhouse at a backwoods cabin location in the fall.

Yes, I'm aware there are regulations about installing outhouses. That's my business.
No, there are no wells, gardens, or other inhabitants anywhere near this location that could be contaminated.
It goes without saying that there are no utilities at this location (water, electric, or sewer).


Outhouses are often unpleasant. Odour is the main issue, but appearance and dampness are also factors.
What can be done to make an outhouse slightly more appealing?
Such as:

Ventilation: A solar-powered fan or a spinning roof vent?
Put sawdust down the hole to dry things out and reduce odors?
Paint the wooden walls and bench to prevent the wood from absorbing odors and moisture?
Moisture-proof container for toilet paper?
Baby wipes or a sink for washing hands.
Anything else?


Have you looked at composting toilets? I read they can even be installed inside a house.

@Willeke Good idea. Yes, I've heard of them. In this case, the living quarters are actually just a homemade camping trailer, not a proper building, so a composing toilet couldn't be installed in the trailer. Maybe a composting toilet could be installed in an outhouse? Not sure. I've heard that they're pricey (my budget is tight) and maybe are more effort than they're worth.

You could have a sink on the inside or out running on a foot pump to take water from a jerry can, probably draining to a soakaway rather than down the hole - but you may have other washing facilities and water/disposal to consider as well

Looks up build it yourself plans.

It can help to use the outhouse just for number two, and piss in the bushes. That avoids the outhouse compost becoming too wet.

At least up here, there are outhouse seats with a separate drain at the front for the liquid stuff, so it doesn't get mixed with the number two. (Won't work if you piss from a standing position, so sit down.)

Outhouses usually have a hole in a bench. Make your bench out of a non-porous material like PVC or metal and invest in a self-sealing plastic toilet seat. Just below the bench you could add a ventilation pipe leading outside which is higher than the outhouse roof. The ventilation pipe should have a fan installed blowing outside which is powerful enough to create an inward draft when your toilet seat is open. Turn this fan on before doing your "business" and turn it off after the "paperwork" is complete.

Other than the sewage plumbing, how much are you willing to invest for a near-indoor-toilet experience? A sink already implies some kind of plumbing, unless you mean a table and bucket.

And watch out for owls! https://blog.nature.org/2017/09/18/owls-outhouse-bathroom-door-foul-bird-issue/

@User1974 I have a composting toilet in an outhouse, and have found it easy to maintain and it's quite odorless. https://www.biolan.com/products/biolan-composting-toilet-eco.html

Regarding the smell
Make sure there is ventilation for the "waste area" which does not lead into the outhouse, but directly outside {1}. At the same time make sure that you have some sort of toilet lid that closes well, close to air-tight if possible, to prevent odours from the waste collecting in the outhouse {2}. In addition make sure that the outhouse is ventilated well to keep any remaining odours in check {3}.
While you are doing your business your behind will mostly form a "lid" which keeps odours away from you.
--> In my experience such a setup will make an outhouse a pleasant experience.
I don't think you need active ventilation - in my experience passive ventilation is enough, if planned correctly and the vent openings are in the proper locations.
                  {3}
                /\
         ______ ||
        /      \//
       /         |
      /          \    {1}
      |          |  /\
      |      {2} |  ||
      |   ____   |  || 
______|___(  )___|__//___
......|          |.//....
......|          |//.....
......|           /......
......|  xxxxxx  |.......
......| xxxxxxxx |.......
......|xxxxxxxxxx|.......
......------------.......
.........................

Covering the waste with sawdust or rock meal will also help to combat odours, and might help with composting / natural decomposition. I would only consider this if the smell becomes an issue though, and/or if the temperature (esp. of the waste containment area) are higher (e.g. in very hot climate, or not isolated in the soil, ...).
Regarding Hygiene
Obviously people should wash/clean their hands after doing their business.

A sink with running water for washing hands is of course nice, but as you said there is no utilities setting one up will mean also setting up water storage and thinking about how to reach the needed pressure. All totally doable, but will be some effort.
As an alternative a sink with some normal soap and just a large jug of water can do the trick as well, and be easy to implement, given there is a nearby place to refill. I'd suggest to not channel the drain into the waste pit, as you'll run the risk of filling it much more quickly...
On the lowest possible end if water is scarce could be to simply provide some sanitary wipes (note that those won't compost in the toilet, so need to be packed out) or hand sanitiser.


Soil is also used for covering, e.g. in Finland.  A trowel's worth is enough, from a bucket kept to hand, to keep the smell down.

Wipes and hand sanitiser for hygiene of there's no water. Sanitiser doesn't work very well on dirty hands, and if you don't have washing facilities there will be dirt, though hopefully not to do with the outhouse.

I like the textual diagram. Very effective.

In BC, there often urine diverters involved (somehow) and wood-shavings or dried leaves  for sprinkling on top -- all to reduce stink and increase composting activity

Having used an outdoor composting toilet for a few years as regular guest in an outdoor cabin location without running water or sewer, here's my takeaway:

Separating liquids from solids is essential for odor reduction. This could mean pissing in the bushes, or installing a little gutter inside at the front of the toilet to divert the urine to a separate container. It takes a bit of practice to get used to it, but it's not difficult to use.
Solids should be generously sprinkled with sawdust or wood shavings. The outhouse will still smell, but it will smell rather like a rodent cage and not of ammonia like a regular outhouse. I was actually surprised at how well this worked.
Composting toilets do not have to be expensive. The one I have used was a DIY project, basically just an outhouse on stilts. Why on stilts? Because it makes removal of the solids much easier, which can then be composted (and used in the garden after a few years)
Pests are a huge problems. Rats will try to get into the toilet and literally eat the solids. Rats are also great at gnawing through almost everything, use wire fence to reinforce things.
A toilet lid is required to keep flies out.
A jug of water and some bio-degradable soap would work well for washing hands, and maybe some hand disinfection gel.


Perhaps you don't need a full outhouse. Perhaps a "boom box" like in the backcountry of some Ontario provincial parks would be better. This is a box over a hole. There's a seat and a lid. There just isn't any "house". This means the smell is not held in. It means you can't store anything there, I suppose, but having to bring the TP each time isn't terrible. You could keep a jug of water in a nearby tree or something if you were up for a week. Or build a sort of separate cabinet that has doors. You could keep your water jug, bowl, soap, and TP in it, and when you're up for a visit put them out on top for easy use.
After all, the walls of the outhouse are mostly so people can't see you doing your business. If you're the only one there, you don't need that. And I can tell you from experience that the extra light and breeze is welcome.

"Boom box", love it.

+1 for doing your business with a view. Though I'd maybe add a tarp overhead.

@Brad They're known as thunder boxes here.

definitely not my idea of a boom box growing up in the US in the 80s

both "boom" and "thunder" come from the sound of the heavy wooden overlid (not the small plastic toilet seat lid) smacking back down again when you're done.

Having used an outhouse at my granddad's place as a kid... I definitely appreciated the plain walls outside the good season. Even in Spring or Fall, a "breeze" can be pretty chilly.

Store-bought bacteria for septic tanks
In addition to construction considerations (which I think are well handled by other answers), I've also found that adding store-bought septic tank bacteria can reduce odor substantially with relatively quick onset (~1 day).
Specifically, we've used septic-tank bacteria successfully to get rid of some extreme odor events when there was a lot of people using a single outhouse at the same time. So not completely sure if you'll see a big effect if your odor levels are already low, but it is an  inexpensive treatment.

Be extra vigilant about screens over the vents and sealing the door. It's going to attract every fly within a few miles. Even if you use it in the fall, you don't want flies to set up shop over the summer and come in to a fly and spider infested area.
Consider a skylight and maybe battery powered night lights in and out to make the trek easier. Maybe put a fly trap or some fly repellent near the front door.

For me personally all the flies and spiders and other insects as well as bad illumination have always been a bigger factor than the smell.
Smell is usually not too bad because there is often plenty of ventilation.
But of course all the gaps for ventilation (as well as natural gaps in the wood construction) allow all kinds of critters in.
If you wanted to do a very serious job you’d make the construction pretty air tight and only have dedicated vents with a fine mesh to prevent insects (or even larger animals) from coming in. Though I imagine it will be pretty difficult. They might even come in through the hole.
Smooth surfaces like tiles or stainless steel would also be easier to clean and keep spotless.

Take a look at what commercial port-a-potties do to help mitigate odors and reduce insect intrusions.  They use a lot of the techniques mentioned by others (good outside ventilation, covered lid, good cross-ventilation inside, non odor-absorbing wall materials, etc.).  They're designed by professionals to make them as non-unpleasant as feasible, so possibly use some of their design ideas for your own needs.

They use a lot of chemicals, still stink, and must be pumped out frequently.

@MartinF I used to make a daily commute past a large highway construction zone, and I would frequently see the trucks delivering new port-a-potties and picking up the old ones for emptying/cleaning, which I'm pretty sure was done at least daily if not more often.  Though these had to serve an entire construction crew, while the OP only needs to serve one person, so it might be more feasible.

In recent years where I live there appeared a new bunch of high quality compost port-a-potties - made from wood, designed in clever ways and they use saw dust instead of chemicals. They work a lot better than the traditional port-a-potties do and rarely smell at all... 100% agree that the cheap ones are maximising profit and not pleasantness of the visit, nor any ecological factors.

My brother used to own a port-a-potty business decades ago, and I'm pretty sure most toilet seats in them just have the seat portion and no lid; the last thing someone in a hurry (or concerned about germs) wants to do is to lift a lid.  I'll have to do some field research at the state fair and get current data!
